# Accessing items in dictionary (python)

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have a data which is stored in a dictionary in python3 with keys as: data, id, index. All datas are stored in the dictionary as `data['data']`. Below is an extract

```
   {'data': array([[7008, 7008, 6080, ..., 4752, 4816, 4688],
               [5824, 5824, 5120, ..., 5264, 5184, 5040],
               [5584, 5584, 4752, ..., 5040, 4928, 4736],
               ..., 
               [4480, 4704, 4304, ..., 4000, 4016, 4096],
               [4624, 4768, 4416, ..., 4064, 3984, 4080],
               [4208, 4464, 4864, ..., 4048, 4112, 3984]], dtype=int64), 

    {'id': array([ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,
           10, 10, 10, 10, 10,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,
            3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,8,
            8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9],dtype=int64)}}
```

and similarly `data[index]` with `dtype=object`.

I have unique 8 indices which are.

```
np.unique(data['index'])
array(['15', '16', 'A', 'A1', 'A2', 'B', 'C', 'D'], dtype=object)
```

Now how can I access the relevant `data['data']` from the indices? Say i want to extract the data for the index value 15. How to extract this.?

```
data['index']
```

returns all the indices and

```
data['data'].data['index'][15]
```

is obviously not the correct approach.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: I think a small example of what your dictionary looks like would be very helpful.

Comment: Why don't you use Python's own dictionary implementation? Ie: what are you trying to accomplish that can't be achieved with an ordinary dict?

Comment: I think what you want is `data['data'][data['index'][15]]`. If not it is not entirely clear :p

Comment: Please provide an [mcve].

Comment: @ImanolLuengo I think that worked. Thanks again. :)